# iText: List of images in a cell

Tags: java, pdf, itext

I would like to create a table that has a list of dots.  I don't know ahead of time how many dots I have, but if they overflow the cell, I want them to wrap, just like text would.  My code is something like this:

```
PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(1);
table.setTotalWidth(new float[]{80});
table.setLockedWidth(true);
Phrase listOfDots = new Phrase();
for (int i = 0; i < 40; i++) {
  listOfDots.add(new Chunk(pdf.correct, 0, 0));
  listOfDots.add(new Chunk(" "));
}
table.addCell(listOfDots);
outerCell.addElement(table);
```

The dots wrap, like I expect, but they don't all have the same size. There are 7 rows of 5 dots each, and all 35 dots have the same size.  The last row of 5 dots are roughly half the size of the others.

(I tried to post an image, but I'm not veteran enough on this site.)

Is there a way to make all the images the same size?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please take a look at the [ImagesInChunkInCell](http://itextpdf.com/sandbox/tables/ImagesInChunkInCell) example. Instead of a bullet, I took the image of a light bulb. I was able to reproduce the problem you described, but as you can see in [list_with_images.pdf](http://itextpdf.com/sites/default/files/list_with_images.pdf), I was able to add one extra line:

```
Image image = Image.getInstance(IMG);
image.setScaleToFitHeight(false);
PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(1);
table.setTotalWidth(new float[]{120});
table.setLockedWidth(true);
Phrase listOfDots = new Phrase();
for (int i = 0; i < 40; i++) {
    listOfDots.add(new Chunk(image, 0, 0));
    listOfDots.add(new Chunk(" "));
}
table.addCell(listOfDots);
```

The extra line is:

```
image.setScaleToFitHeight(false);
```

This prevents that the image is scaled.